# Is it correct to say "oxygen masks were donned on passengers"?

Tags: verbs, questions

I'm in doubt. I don't know what preposition should be used after don. I couldn't find any. However I found that don means put on... Is it correct to say "oxygen masks were donned on passengers"?

Comment: Generally things are donned _by_ a person.

Comment: You sort of answered your own question: _don_ means _put on_. So . . . **Active voice**: _Passengers donned [put on] oxygen masks._ **Passive voice**: _Oxygen masks were donned [put on] by passengers._

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: _Don_ is derived from an old expression _do on_, so it doesn't need another preposition.

Answer (score 7):

*Don* means "put clothes on oneself".

You can say

> The passengers donned oxygen masks.

or

> Oxygen masks were donned by passengers.

(*Don* is not a very common word, and it sounds odd to me to use it of oxygen masks; but it is perfectly understandable).

Comment: My inclination would not be to use "don" either. But I can understand why it has been - because there really isn't another verb which means "put on",  and that sounds a bit awkward in the passive.  Without it, one really is restricted to "The passengers put on oxygen masks".